# Standard text for asking people to provide references etc

Tags: support, answers, questions

I have seen some of the diamond mods provide good quality comments that ask people to provide references or to let someone know that they need to improve their post etc.

Can I please get the exact text of these as they are polite and to the point and would be handy if they were somewhere I could find them. They say something along the lines of 'this site is for asking notable claims as indicated in the FAQ', but I don't think search covers comments so I can never find them when I'm in a hurry.

Comment: You can check the activity tab on the user profile to find comments by a specific moderator.

Comment: @Fabian - Smart thinking, I never thought of that, but do you still think it's worthwile to have them here for other non-diamond mods otherwise I will delete the question if it's not worthwhile for others to have them.

Comment: Templates are useful, I don't like to use them too much, but as long as you adapt them a bit to the situation they are fine. Collecting them here is useful, so the question should IMHO stay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our new [Guidelines for Inadequately Referenced Answers](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/guidelines-for-inadequately-referenced-answers) include some suggestions:

> Welcome to Skeptics! Please [provide some references](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5) to support your claims.

---

> Could you please [provide a reference](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5) for your claim that the tallest ever person was 2.72m?

---

> I can't find in that source any evidence to directly support your claim that the tallest ever person was 2.72m. Could you please quote the relevant section or find another reference?

---

I prefer to customise my answers, but I do use the first one as a template with the [AutoReviewComments](https://gist.github.com/842025) userscript as a basis, or when I am being <strike>lazy</strike> efficient. It adds the "Welcome to Skeptics!" prelude only if the user is new (by some arbitrary rule).