# Why was my answer deleted so fast?

Tags: support

My answer to a [question was deleted](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/30727/is-it-more-harmful-to-eat-sugary-food-when-sick/30732#30732) within minutes of posting. It was commented on in an extremely obnoxious manner mere seconds after posting by the same person. May I know why?

Answer (score 9):

Your question starts:

> My answer to a question was deleted within minutes of posting.

Under the [Guidelines for Inadequately Referenced Answers](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/guidelines-for-inadequately-referenced-answers) it states:

> - If one week has passed and no-one has added references, or if the author explicitly declines to add references before then, that the moderator feels is necessary, then the moderator may add a comment and delete the post.

You explicitly declined to provide references in your comment, which allowed me to delete the answer, which I did so happily. It was a low-quality answer, expressing a rather dubious opinion about how the immune system works (and used the word "chemical" unscientifically).

You go on in your question to say:

> It was commented on in an extremely obnoxious manner mere seconds after posting by the same person.

That "extremely obnoxious" comment was this:

> Please [provide some references](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5) to support your claims.

I'll admit, it didn't include my standard "Welcome to Skeptics!" introduction, because you have been a member for 18 days, and the script I use assumes that if you have been around for that long, you'd have seen it by then.

After you posted an incomprehensible defence of "Common sense" not requiring references, I realised you had never read the welcome message, and made sure my second comment included that link.

While I don't want my comments to come across as obnoxious, your attitude in your comment, the slurs against me in the original draft of this question, and your comment on George's answer makes me feel like this isn't really about *my* attitude.

Answer (score 7):

With all respect, the rules here is that you need to reference your answers, your deleted [answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/30732/20749) was:

> Rule of thumb is that in most (hardly all, though) cases it is not advisable to eat much of anything when you're sick. That's because your body should be focusing on fighting the disease rather than digesting grub.
>
> That said, it is NEVER advisable to eat junk food. It has way more sugar and chemicals that even a healthy body can safely process.

Skeptics Stack Exchange is not a website to gather opinions. It is not just you, most unreferenced answers get deleted. To fix your answer, you need to add a reference.

**Add a reference to your answer, then flag for moderator attention, and it might get undeleted.**

Comment: Yeah, okay, this is not merely unprofessional, but downright boring. You guys are not skeptics at all: you just want to come across as original. So long.

Comment: Are you describing your own behaviour? It does seem unprofessional to jump into answering a question without having reviewed good answers and the FAQ, to offer unreferenced opinions as fact, and to then become petulant when people try to guide you in how the site works. If so, I'll gladly vote up your comment for the wonderful use of irony.