# What is to be done about a mis-attributed image?

Tags: discussion, citations, images

[This answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/54356/48433) to the question, "Did JK Rowling ever describe Harry Potter goblins as 'hook-nosed'?" is built around an illustration that is claimed to be from the original 1974 publication of *Dungeons & Dragons* (D&D), but it's not.

The [details page at Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:DnD_Goblin.png) for the image (where the poster got it) documents that the image is a fan work from 2017, credited to the uploader of the image, illustrating the work of J.R.R. Tolkien (so, not related to D&D, nor of the right time era).

I've pointed this out to the poster in comments. They thanked me, but declined to remove the image or change the mis-attribution.

I submitted an edit to the question replacing it with an actual illustration from the 1974 D&D publication. The poster commented, "I appreciate the find", but rejected the edit.

Is there anything else to be done at this point? Or does the site just live with the misinformation now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have a process for [inadequately referenced answers](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/guidelines-for-inadequately-referenced-answers).

In this case, two parts of the answer were poorly referenced:

- The key claim that hook-nosed goblins in folklore were not seen as referencing Jews (despite a comment by @Avery pointing out some historical links between the two).
- A claim that a picture (found on Wikipedia) was from the First Edition of Dungeons and Dragons (despite it being a modern take, created after the Harry Potter movies).

The OP took several actions to reject or revert edits that attempted to fix the latter, which I interpreted as an refusal to add references, so I have since deleted the answer in accordance with the process.

Comment: Thanks for the link & moderation.