# How else could this have been answered, if not by logic?

Tags: discussion

There is this [question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/38829/40957) about an elementary property of Quranic verse numbers. The question was put on hold (rightly so, I believe, because it's arithmetic).

What astounds me is that below the *answer* there is the complaint:

> We do not allow answers based uniquely on common sense or pure logic.

First, it seems to contradict [this](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1019/how-to-handle-answers-based-on-logic), wherein it is said that:

> The problem is obviously not the logic part, it is that the logic depends on uncited facts.

In my naive(?) view, the nature of the question allows but for this single kind of answer. If you are starting to call the properties of numbers into question, every answer here that presupposes any calculation (be it the simplest addition) must be taken down. That doesn't seem too productive. The right course of action is to close the question as off topic or move it to an other community.

What's more, as far as I see, the answer *constructs* an analogous arithmetic example, which, I think, is as experimental as it can get.

> Why did moderation suggest to the answerer he answer this in any different manner? What kind of answer would have been better?

Is it not in the interest of everyone, if the question and answer be moved to an other community, rather than forcing upon the answerer some very peculiar choice of answer?

Answer (score 1):

> If you are starting to call the properties of numbers into question, every answer here that presupposes any calculation (be it the simplest addition) must be taken down

Clearly if an existing entity has a mathematical property, it must be possible to create an entity with such property. The answer shows one such way.

On the other hand, the question is *not* about a mathematical property of an abstract entity, but about a specific book, which has a specific history, where either such a property was constructed on purpose or it was not; where it is due to pareidolia or it is not; where either such a thing happened via an apparent miracle or it did not.

All questions on skeptics are about factual events, never about pure maths. This is the reason of the banner and its existence.

> What kind of answer would have been better?

One that documents how those verses were composed, or whether Muslim scholars consider it a miracle or mere coincidence.

But this is all in theory since the question is closed and questions are closed because they should not be answered. Someone just got there before I could close it.

> Is it not in the interest of everyone, if the question and answer be moved to an other community, rather than forcing upon the answerer some very peculiar choice of answer?

Not in my opinion: the question is very speculative and the answer does not really address it. The OP is free to open the same question, but tailored to a different community.

Comment: The answer is NOT mine!

Comment: Also, I don't see how 'Is this extraordinary and miraculous or is there a clear rejection to this claim?' Could be answered by the CLAIMS of Muslim scholars. Clearly, the religiously conditioned answer is even less skeptical than the mathematical one. Anyway, you clarified the general situation very well.

Comment: @Ludi Apologies, corrected the mistake. I know that the religious perspective is also going to be a claim, but certainly if religious authorities claim it's a miracle, this is a fact that we ought to include, it's part of the evidence--certainly not high quality, objective evidence, but evidence nonetheless.

Comment: Your first claim isn't particularly correct, depending on what you mean by "existing entity".  Often in mathematics we can prove that things exist without being able to actually construct such an object. A concrete construction of something known to exist (or be true, more broadly) can be a highly non-trivial problem, and [may even be impossible](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/755375/92067).

Comment: If something exists, then there's no need to prove it's constructable. It's certainly possible to write the Koran as is. Just ...copy it.